# Concern on the stitching after dog castration

Tags: dogs

I had my 6 months old pup castrated earlier today and everything seems to have gone fine. He seems like himself and has a lot of energy and doesn't seem in any pain.

I'm worried about the stitching though: it looks very messy. The two sides of the wound isn't aligned well, causing about a 4mm section of the one side to protrude past the other. Perhaps it can be best explained via the photo below. The photo is taken at a slight angle. The red portion is where the flesh, or whatever that is considered biologically, protrudes past the other side.

I'm guessing at the very least this will result in an ugly scar, but do I have to worry about infections and/or the wound not healing properly? If possible I'd like to avoid the trauma of having to redo the stitches, but not if there are any health concerns with leaving it as it is.

[image: Stitching]

Comment: Looks ok, I was also over worried when my pup had the operation but everything just heals up over time.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't worry too much about it. The stitches should keep the wound closed and the tiny open part on the outside is merely like a cut finger: It might look ugly, there might even be some tissue fluid or pus on the surface, but it should be fine.

Just keep an eye on the wound and keep it clean, e.g. don't let your dog sit in dirty water or mud for the next few days.

In case anything else happens, like the thread going loose, the wound opening, or some inflammation happening, talk to your vet.

Comment: @Woofer your veterinarian should had give the dog come medication for consumption and some external medication for clean its wounds twice a day. Follow the veterinarian's instruction for the one whole week, and your dog should be fine :)